# ADD or COPY a folder in Docker

Tags: docker

My directory Structure as follows

```
 Dockerfile downloads
```

I want to add downloads to /tmp

```
 ADD downloads /tmp/
 COPY down* /tmp
 ADD ./downloads /tmp
```

Nothings works. It copies the contents of downloads into tmp. I want to copy the downloads floder. Any idea?

```
 ADD . tmp/
```

copies Dockerfile also. i dont want to copy Dockerfile into tmp/

Answer (score 85):

I believe that you need:

```
COPY downloads/ /tmp/downloads/
```

That will copy the contents of the downloads directory into a directory called `/tmp/downloads/` in the image.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 64):

***Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents***

From the dockerfile reference about `COPY` and `ADD`, it says `Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.`, so you have to specify a dest directory explicitly.

RE: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

e.g.

Copy the content of the `src` directory to `/some_dir/dest_dir` directory.

```
COPY ./src    /some_dir/dest_dir/
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use:

```
RUN mkdir -p /path/to/your/new/folder/
COPY /host/folder/ /path/to/your/new/folder/
```

I could not find a way to do it directly with only one `COPY` call though.

Comment: Updating this answer with `-p` arg for `mkdir` which lets you make nested folders. `COPY` not creating the nested folders I needed was my issue, and this answer has the best fix.

Answer (score 6):

The best for me was:

```
COPY . /tmp/
```

With following **.dockerignore** file in root

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
# Other files you don't want to copy
```

This solution is good if you have many folders and files that you need in container and not so many files that you don't need.
Otherwise [user2807690' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599571/add-or-copy-a-folder-in-docker#30864127) is better.

Answer (score 3):

First tar the directory you want to ADD as a single archive file:

```
tar -zcf download.tar.gz download
```

Then ADD the archive file in Dockerfile:

```
ADD download.tar.gz tmp/
```

Comment: Increasing complexity by inroducing  unnecessary things

Answer (score -3):

If you folder does not end with a `/`it is considered a file, so you should something like write `ADD /abc/ def/` if you want to copy a folder.

Comment: No Man, It doesn't work. `ADD downloads/ /mnt/` But it adds the content of downloads into /mnt/.

Comment: both your folders source AND destination must end with a `/`, your try copying also your Dockerfile shows this is correct.

Comment: Leave the Dockerfile. I just commented what i have tried. It s also not working

Comment: I am sure this works `COPY download/ /tmp/` let me know

Comment: Just tried `COPY src/ /app/` and the content of src gets copied over. This is on docker version `17.03.1-ce`