# In Docker, how do I share a volume from a container to a host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know you can share a directory that exists on the host with a container using the VOLUMES directive, but I'd like to do the opposite--share the files that exist in the container with the host, provided that nothing exists in that directory on the host.

The use case for this is that we have contractors, and we'd like to provide them with a docker container that contains all the code and infrastructure they need to work with, but that would allow them to alter that code by running PyCharm or some other program on their local machine without having to worry about committing the container, ...etc.

Comment: Isn't this what SCC is for?   Anyhow, every directory in the container lives on the host somewhere.    Do a docker inspect and see where....

Comment: What does SCC stand for?

Comment: Source Code Control.   git/cvs etc.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to save (persist) data, Docker came up with the concept of volumes. basically `Volumes` are directories (or files) that are outside of the default Union File System and exist as normal directories and files on the host filesystem.

You can declare a volume at run-time with the -v flag:

```
$ docker run -it --name container1 -v /data debian /bin/bash
```

This will make the directory `/data` inside the container live outside the Union File System and directly accessible on the host. Any files that the image held inside the `/data` directory will be copied into the volume. We can find out where the volume lives on the host by using the docker inspect command on the host.

Open a new terminal and leave the previous container running and run:

```
$ docker inspect container1
```

The output will provide details on the container configurations including the volumes. 
The output should look something similar to the following:

```
...
Mounts": [
    {
        "Name": "fac362...80535",
        "Source": "//var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/cde167197ccc3e/_data",
        "Destination": "/data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
]
...
```

Telling us that Docker has mounted `/data` inside the container as a directory somewhere under `/var/lib/docker` in the host.

Comment: Thanks a great answer, thank you, but as I understand it, if every container that references that volume is removed, then that volume is also removed. If possible, I would like for the data to persist.

Comment: According with my understanding the volumes are designed to persist data, independent of the container’s life cycle. Data volumes persist even if the container itself is deleted.

Comment: I'm removing the accepted answer flag from this question because the solution only works on Linux. On Windows and OSX, docker-machine uses VirtualBox, which doesn't expose the directory where the volume lies.

We're back to square one. Contractors cannot access volumes in containers.

Comment: If you are using `docker-machine` on Mac or Windows, you can have the same behavior that linux as long as you use the path `/Users/<...>`. Because by default `docker-machine` tries to auto-share your `/Users` (OS X) or `C:\Users` (Windows) directory. Please be more specific on your question next time.

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned the docker-machine thing. I get that the users volume is shared... so your advice is to put my code into /Users/docker in the image, and then share that directory? That wouldn't work on a Mac, right? I don't think a user can access another user's directory like that.

Really appreciate your time on this.

Comment: It will work on Mac as long the shared folder is located somewhere under /Users directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) you can easily [`ADD` or `COPY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599571/add-or-copy-a-folder-in-docker) whole directory.

I guess this is what you are looking for. Otherwise you can just share the code and at the `docker run` so they can volume-mount the shared code.

Comment: This allows me to copy data into an image, sure, but in order to access it, my contractors would have to bash into the container. Additionally, they couldn't easily make changes without committing the docker container, which is something I mentioned in the question that I didn't want them to do.

Comment: I agree, hence my last sentence: "Otherwise you can just share the code aside the image and at the `docker run` they can volume-mount the shared code." So the code can be modified without committing. The code should _not_ be _in_ the image actually, that's a bad practice (because of the commiting operation required then).